# Medusa Brute Force doesn't work

Tags: brute-force

I tried to run *medusa* in Ubuntu to do brute-force attack with testing purpose. But when I tried to enter the following code to terminal,

```
medusa -h localhost/includekarabuk/adminPaneli/index.php -u sankiolurgibi -P Desktop/includekarabuk.lst -M ssh
```

I came accross this output(problem):

```
Medusa v2.1.1 [http://www.foofus.net] (C) JoMo-Kun / Foofus Networks <jmk@foofus.net>

CRITICAL: Failed to resolve hostname: localhost/includekarabuk/adminPaneli/index.php - Name or service not known
```

How can I accomplish this problem? Anyone has idea?

Comment: `-h` wants a hostname. `localhost` is a hostname. `localhost/includekarabuk/adminPaneli/index.php` is the path to a web page on that host.

Comment: Thank you for this information. Well, how should I edit my code? I mean do you know how I can add "path" into my code?

Comment: I'm *guessing* you're trying to test against a web form. If so, looks like you want the web-form module. Examples here: http://www.aldeid.com/wiki/Medusa#Example

Answer (score 2):

The parameter `-h` is for `hostname` you need to put only the hostname there.
Also, the parameter `-M` is set to `ssh`, it should be `web-form` instead.

follow this guide to effectively bruteforce: [Medusa Web bruteforce](http://www.aldeid.com/wiki/Medusa#form-web)

a valid example goes like:

```
$ medusa \
-h 127.0.0.1 \
-u admin \
-P /data/dict/dict.txt \
-M web-form \
-m FORM:"admin/test.php" \
-m DENY-SIGNAL:"ACCESS DENIED" \
-m FORM-DATA:"post?u=&p=&Login=Login"
```

Comment: It worked, but not properly. The attack is carried out with just one trial-error out of 1786. Then it stopped and said [SUCCESS]. So there is still a problem.

Comment: As per the reference page, `[SUCCESS]` is returned when the login is successful, Medusa has a configuration where it stops further processing when it finds first valid login. Check if you have specified that option. run `medusa -h` on the terminal to find the options.